# Return categories and subcategories from a Rest API with POSTMAN : null and no subcategories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I created an Java Entity class for "Categories":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String categoryKeyId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //Here mappedBy indicates that the owner is in the other side
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductEntity> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private CategoryEntity parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<CategoryEntity> subCategory;
}
```

Then I created a repository class :

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CategoryEntity, Long> {
    Page<CategoryEntity> findBySubCategoryNotNull(Pageable pageableRequest);
}
```

In my controller

```
@GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public List<CategoryRest> getTopCategoriesWithSubCategories(@RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue="0") int page, @RequestParam(value="limit", defaultValue="5") int limit) {
    List<CategoryRest> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();

    List<CategoryDto> categoryDtos = categoryService.getTopCategoriesWithSubCategories(page, limit);

    // loop the result
    for (CategoryDto categoryDto : categoryDtos) {
        CategoryRest categoryRest = new CategoryRest();
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        categoryRest = modelMapper.map(categoryDto, CategoryRest.class);
        returnValue.add(categoryRest);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

For this I use a service that uses a method in a service.

```
@Override
public List<CategoryDto> getTopCategoriesWithSubCategories(int page, int limit) {
    List<CategoryDto> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();

    if (page > 0) page -= 1;
    Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(page, limit);

    Page<CategoryEntity> categoriesPage = categoryRepository.findBySubCategoryNotNull(pageableRequest);
    List<CategoryEntity> categoryEntities = categoriesPage.getContent();

    for(CategoryEntity categoryEntity: categoryEntities) {
        CategoryDto categoryDto = new CategoryDto();
        returnValue.add(categoryDto);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

My CategoryRest is very basic :

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryRest {
    // data that is returned when a category is created
    private String categoryKeyId;
    private String categoryName;
    private List<CategoryRest> subCategories;
}
```

I have 2 issue when i try to get the result. I obtain null results. 
Concerning getting the list of subcategories, it must be an issue with my logic with my JPA request (probably)

Answer (score 0):

Never forget to annotate your Dto Layer with @Getter @Setter if you use Lombok or  set the getter and setter ... Too stupid mistake that can happen